# Double sigma summation is in complexity calculation

Tags: summation, computational-complexity

Basically i was reading skiena and doing exercise of 2nd chapter.The result of my calculation got differed from the actual solution given on [Solution site](http://nbl.cewit.stonybrook.edu:60128/mediawiki/index.php/TADM2E_2.1)
and there is one thing i don't understand how to prove

[image]

Is only method to prove is induction?

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^n j=(i+1)+\ldots+n=(1+\ldots+i)+[(i+1)+\ldots+n]-(1+\ldots+i)=\sum_{j=1}^n j-\sum_{j=1}^i j$$

Comment: thanks but what if i do like $$\sum_{j=i+1}^n j=(i+1)+(i+2)+(i+3)+\ldots+(i+n-1)+n=n*i+[(1)+\ldots+n]=\sum_{j=1}^n i+\sum_{j=1}^n 1$$